# Migrating Host Named Site Collections to SharePoint Online

Tags: sharepoint-online, site-collection

Is it possible to migrate on premises host named site collections to SharePoint Online while preserving the host names?

[This support link indicates it may not be possible.](http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/156/t/234199.aspx)

[This MSFT recommendation link](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/russmax/archive/2013/10/31/guide-to-sharepoint-2013-host-name-site-collections.aspx) says that using on premises HNSC makes moving to SPO easier.

Answer (score 2):

SharePoint Online doesn't support host named site collections, so no.

Comment: Why is the claim being made that using HNSC on premises will make moving to SPO easier?